# bearer token authentication with web api 1

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on implementing token based authentication in ASP.NET WebAPI.
Is it possible to implement bearer token authentication in WebAPI 1.2?

**update:**

The problem is all the examples i see is based on WebAPI 2 and OWIN. WebAPI 2 came up with a dedicated authenticate attribute, but i am looking for WebAPI 1.2 it only having authorize attribute. We need to override the onAuthorize method and implement the token validation logic. but i dont know how to implement bearer token and set expiry time for that token. more over how to generate a new token if  a token is expired. somewhere do i need to store the generated token inorder to validate?

```
public class APIAuthentication : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeader = "WWW-Authenticate";
    private const string BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue = "Basic";

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //logics for perform bearer token auth.
        //if auth failed we ill be return 401 and auth type in header
        HandleUnAuthorized(actionContext);
    }

    private void HandleUnAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        actionContext.Response.Headers.Add(BasicAuthResponseHeader, BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Gowrish.

Comment: anythings possible-- what have you tried..? did you try a simple google search.. here is an example if you know `Angular.js` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A

Comment: i tried but i dont know how to validate a bearer token since WebAPI is a stateless how do we can validate a bearer token? we need to store each users token somewhere in API right? Is that a correct way?

Comment: The bearer token should be validated by WebAPI by way of the `[Authorize]` attribute.  The token is encrypted and isn't persisted to storage by the WebAPI if that is what you were meaning...

Comment: Assume, inorder to make the unique token for each time the user log in i would create a token based on date time so inorder to validate the token wont we need to store the generated token somewhere, so that we can validate the forthcoming request tokens against stored tokens?